# add/remove a class to multiple instances of same the same ID

Tags: javascript, html, animation, delay

I have this add/remove function working on only the first instance of that the "sineDelay" id, but can't get it to run on every instance of the "sineDelay" id. I'd like  clicking on a the button to add it to every instance of that id. Please help, thanks :)

```js
function $delSinSlowTight() {
  var element = document.getElementById("sineDelay");
  element.classList.remove("delSinMedTight");
  element.classList.add("delSinSlowTight");
}

function $delSinMedTight() {
  var element = document.getElementById("sineDelay");
  element.classList.remove("delSinSlowTight");
  element.classList.add("delSinMedTight");
}
```

```css
.circleDelayFunction {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #3878fe, #a173fe);
}

.delSinSlowTight{
  animation: oscillate 2s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-play-state: running;


  @for $i from 1 through 6 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
     animation-delay: ( #{sin(.15) * ($i)}s );
    }
}}

.delSinMedTight{
  animation: oscillate 1s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation-play-state: running;


  @for $i from 1 through 6 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
     animation-delay: ( #{sin(.25) * ($i)}s );
    }
}}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div id="sineDelay" class="circleDelayFunction delSinSlowTight"></div>
  <div id="sineDelay" class="circleDelayFunction delSinSlowTight"></div>
  <div id="sineDelay" class="circleDelayFunction delSinSlowTight"></div>
  <div id="sineDelay" class="circleDelayFunction delSinSlowTight"></div>
  <div id="sineDelay" class="circleDelayFunction delSinSlowTight"></div>
  <div id="sineDelay" class="circleDelayFunction delSinSlowTight"></div>
</div>

<li><button class="button--delay" onclick="$delSinSlowTight()">$delSinSlowTight</button></li>
<li><button class="button--delay" onclick="$delSinMedTight()">$delSinMedTight</button></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML IDs are designed to be single instance attributes. Try assigning a class to all of the elements that you want to update and then using `document.getElementsByClassName("circleDelayFunction")` to get an array of all of the elements.  You can then loop through the array to manipulate the elements.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible using `document.getElementById` as it returns only the first element that matches the given id or null if there is no such element. If you want to target all of the `div` elements with that id. Use something like:

```
function $delSinSlowTight() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].classList.remove("delSinMedTight");
        elements[i].classList.add("delSinSlowTight");
    }
```

}

And the same goes for the other function. Also, id should be unique, meaning that there shouldn't be two or more elements in the document that share the same id. Technically, it is possible to have multiple elements that share the same id but it is always considered to be a bad practice.